# Static const member initialization outside class

Tags: c++

how can i  initialize static const int member outside class ?

```
class C
{

public:
    C();

private:
    static const int a;
    static const std::string b;

};

// const int C::a = 4;               //  i know it 
// const std::string  C::b = "ba";  //  this one too
```

Comment: What is the point of having `static` and `const` applied to the same variable?

Comment: @Logicrat the value of a **static** data member can be changed unless it is declared as `const`.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is there a way you want to initialize `b` that does not work?

Comment: if you want to receive  static array  you must  know  your arrays size   , static const  int member is good way to do it.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov  i want to know  how can i initialize static const member  ,  is there a way?

Comment: You already do that in the part you commented out, so what's wrong with that approach?

Comment: @t.niese  besides this option is there another?

Comment: `how can i initialize static const int member outside class ?` `besides this option is there another?` You already show how to initialize them **outside** of the class, why do you look for another option? What do you expect from another option that you can't do with the one you show in your question? What do you not like about the one you already know?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Yes, a static member can change if it's not `const`, but given that it is `const` I don't see a reason to make it static.

Comment: @Logicrat • the reason to make it `static` is the same as the reason to make any variable or function in a class `static`.  Just because it is `const` doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to initialize static class members outside of the class:

**C.cpp**

```
#include <string>

class C {
public:
    C();

private:
    static const int a;
    static const std::string b;
};

C::C() = default;

const int C::a = 4;
const std::string C::b = "ba";
```

There is no other option to initialize a static class member outside of the class, other than all the various C++ ways to do initialization as variations on this same theme.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with `C++17` and use `inline static` object:

```
class C
{

public:
    C() = default;
private:
    inline static const int a = 42;
    inline static const std::string b{"foo"};

};
```

Easiest, cleaniest, most readable.

Comment: While I personally agree that this is probably the cleanest way to do it, the question is `how can i initialize static const int member outside class ?`  and that one is not **outside** of the class. Maybe it is what the OP is looking for, but then the question is asked incorrectly by the OP.

Comment: @t.niese  please read carefully.  I want to initialaize  members   out of class.  Can i do it??

Comment: @user12918858 I didn't say anything else in my comment?

Comment: @user12918858 to me it is a https://xyproblem.info: you're asking about how to handle a case that is already solved in modern C++: no need to discuss initialization outside the class if it can (and should) be done where it's declared (so inside, with `inline`).

Comment: @Quarra and how to initialize from main?

Comment: If it needs to be initialized from main, then most probably it doesn't belong to the class in the first place, hence XY problem. Entities shall be defined as close as possible to where they are declared.